SN increament after 3 way handshake
After the three-way handshake, when receiving an ACK from the server, what is the value of the SN in the ACK? Data is being transmitted only from client to server.

TCP diagram

Your question does not match what is asked in your picture. The question is about after TCP handshake, the picture is about FIN. In short: FIN advances the seq by 1. Apart from that these look like homework question, so please try to solve them first yourself and share your own thoughts.

I have an exam in 5 hours. My question is: what should I put in the SN field at step 5 — 200 or 201?

If you are able to understand my comment ("FIN advances the seq by 1") then you should be able to derive the answer easily. If not then you are probably not fit for the exam since you don't understand enough of how TCP works. Just giving you the exact answer would not help since you need the deeper understanding to handle similar questions.
